# Switch populated on ODL web topology cannot be removed

Tags: opendaylight, mininet

I'm running ODL(beryllium) and test openflow environment using mininet.

Everything is OK until I clean up everything from mininet as the switch on the web topology is still there.

I've tried using mn -c but the switch remain in the topology view.

I know there is a command to force remove and cleanup topology from the ODL terminal, but I can't find it.

Does anyone know the command so that I can remove it and clean my ODL?

Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

run "ovs-vsctl show" on your mininet system to see if any extra ovs instance(s)
are running. the web GUI you are looking at should just be a reflection of the
operational store of ODL, and the operational store should just be a reflection
of any switches that are still connected to the openflow plugin of ODL.

I dont know of any ODL command that will clean up mininet though.

Comment: Hi..thanks..from my mininet I'm getting below 8f53a878-a9fc-485b-b657-1edd245931a7
    ovs_version: "2.5.5"

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean by getting that node-id from your mininet. Does that mean it's an ovs node connected to ODL?

Comment: I have done clearing from mininet 'mn -c' but ODL topology view still showing the switches... I even create new ODL with boron version .... and run it again....and surprisingly the switches is still there...(im not even run mininet yet) ...so what do you think the issue?

Comment: if mininet is not running and you are seeing a switch connected to ODL then some other switch is running/connecting somewhere. like I mentioned before, run "ovs-vsctl show" on any systems in the environment to see if you've got some OVS connected. Whatever switch it is, it's configured to connect to a specific IP so rebuilding and running a new ODL will just end up with that same switch connecting to it.

Answer (score 0):

Try `mn -c` as super user it will solve this problem.

```
sudo mn -c
```